# SAS: How to increment datetime macro variable inside a loop

Tags: sas

I need to do a repeating task in 3 days interval from a start date (myDate), so I am trying to increment myDate by 3 in the loop for 100 times. I am having some trouble with the syntax.

```
%MACRO DO_LIST (myDate);
%DO I = 1 %TO 100;
    format newDate datetime22.;
    newDate = INTNX('dtday', &myDate, 3);
    call symput('myDate', newDate);
%END;
%mend DO_LIST;

%LET sampleDate  = '01JAN2017:0:0:0'dt;
%DO_LIST (sampleDate);

%put &sampleDate;
```

This is the error. I tried to move around and different way to store and update within my loop.

```
NOTE: Line generated by the invoked macro "DO_LIST".
25                                        newDate = INTNX('day', &myDate, 3)  call symput('myDate', newDate);
                                          _______
                                          180

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper orde
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a macro loop, not a data step loop. You will need to use the macro language and functions in order to increment the variable within the loop, and ensure that the returned value is global in scope. Data step functions are not available in open code, unless its results are saved to a macro variable. The corrected code is below:

```
%MACRO DO_LIST (myDate);
    %global newDate;

    %DO I = 1 %TO 100;
        %let newDate = %sysfunc(INTNX(dtday, &myDate, 3), mdyampm.);
    %END;
%mend DO_LIST;

%LET sampleDate  = '01JAN2017:00:00:00'dt;
%DO_LIST (&sampleDate);

%put &newDate;
```

The equivalent can be done in a data step loop:

```
data _null_;
    format newdate mdyampm.;

    do i = 1 to 100;
        newDate = intnx('dtday', '01JAN2017:00:00:00'dt, 3);
    end;

    put newDate;

    call symputx('newdate', newdate, 'G');
run;
```

Comment: Your explanation is very clear and I appreciate the supplemental data step solution. I am looping some PROC SQL queries with this, so both are extremely helpful.